# search function look for parameter's value in related table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables, merchants and transaction. merchants has (mid,name,age) and transaction has (id,mid,order_no,). I have displayed the data like (orderid,name) with eagerloading. now i have a search function on top where , i can search for all the orders by the merchant's name. how do i do that? im' trying something like this

```
  public function search($search){
      $query = Transaction::with('themerchant')
      ->join('merchants','transactions.mid', '=', 'merchants.mid' )
      ->select('merchants.name', '=' , '%'.$search.'%')->paginate(10);
      return $query;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh you are using eagerLoading
Do this

```
public function search($search){
  return Transaction::with(['themerchant' => function($query){
      $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
  }])->paginate(10);;
```

}

If you want an exact merchant match change the where like this

```
...
->where('name', '=' , $search)
...
```

If you want to use Join

```
public function search($search){
    return Transaction::join('merchants', 'merchants.mid', '=', 'transactions.mid')
    ->where('merchants.name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->get();
}
```

Comment: Please check again. You are using eagerLoading I updated.

Comment: Do you have a relationship setup in your models? So you can display the data properly with eager loading? Like `$tr = Transaction::with('themerchant')->first();` Try that and tell if it works.

Comment: Oohhh sorry my bad. I forgot to add `paginate(10)` at the end. Please try again with the new update. If paginate doesnt work, try to replace paginate(10) with `get()`.

Comment: yes it works, i dd($tr), i see that i shows me the data. i have set the relationships in the model already before.

Comment: like in my view..im not showing anything from the Merchants table.... what im trying to show is the transaction table's content by relating the merchants name.

Comment: Try with the join I just added in my answer. If it still does work, show me how you pass your `$search` variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136419/discussion-between-eddythedove-and-mohamed-manas).

Comment: its working! with join ....  thxx Eddy why didnt it work with the eagerloading way??